# Function not saving var for use later. (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell

I bet this is a dumb question but im having issue with this code... When I run the contents of the function outside of the function it works just fine I can write-console without issues. However running under the function not so much... Not sure why this is, if anyone can let me know what im missing that would be great. The goal is to run the Preuptime Function before the reboot and Post after, then using the result into an email.

Thanks
Cody

```
    $startupvariables
# Store all the start up variables so you can clean up when the script finishes.
if ($startupvariables) { try {Remove-Variable -Name startupvariables  -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } catch { } }
New-Variable -force -name startupVariables -value ( Get-Variable | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } ) 


$date = Get-Date
$server = 'SGSQL1', 'SGSQL2', 'appv1', 'appv2', 'sltappv4'

$emailSmtpServer = "exmbx6"
$emailFrom = "gordonc@"
$emailTo = "retinaAlert@"
$emailSubject = "Result: Reboot report for $server $date" 
$emailSubjectF = "Stuff Failed"
$emailBody = @"
<p><strong>Todays Date</strong>:$date</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Server: SGSQL1</p>
<p> <strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr11</p>
<p> <strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SGSQL2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv1</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$spr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$apr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SltAppv4</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$spr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$spr12</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Please close the Event Notifcation in FootPrints</p>
"@
$emailBodyF = @"
<p>THINGS FAILD</p>
"@

Function Preuptime{
$sgs11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$sgr11 = $sgs11.ConvertToDateTime($sgs11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$sgs21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$sgr21 = $sgs21.ConvertToDateTime($sgs21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$apr11 = $app11.ConvertToDateTime($app11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$apr21 = $app21.ConvertToDateTime($app21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$spp11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"
$spr11 = $spp11.ConvertToDateTime($spp11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
}

Function Postuptime{
$sgs12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$sgr12 = $sgs12.ConvertToDateTime($sgs12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$sgs22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$sgr22 = $sgs22.ConvertToDateTime($sgs22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$apr12 = $app12.ConvertToDateTime($app12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$apr22 = $app22.ConvertToDateTime($app22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$spp12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"
$spr12 = $spp12.ConvertToDateTime($spp12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
}
Function FailedEmail {
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubjectF -Body $emailBodyF -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer -BodyAsHtml
}
Function WorkedEmail {
Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $emailSubject -Body $emailBody -SmtpServer $emailSmtpServer -BodyAsHtml
}
Function ServerReboot {
foreach($server in $servers){
            ping -n 2 $server >$null
            if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
                #Restart-Computer -Wait -For Wmi $server
            } else {
                FailedEmail
                }
            }
}

PreUptime
ServerReboot
PostUptime
WorkedEmail

Function Clean-Memory {
Get-Variable |
 Where-Object { $startupVariables -notcontains $_.Name } |
 ForEach-Object {
  try { Remove-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Force -Scope "global" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
  catch { }
 }
}
```

I had to put the email body and such right under the last bit of the Post reboot times to make it pull the right info... With out it the result were just blank.. Weird anyone know why?

```
$sgs12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$sgr12 = $sgs12.ConvertToDateTime($sgs12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$sgs22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$sgr22 = $sgs22.ConvertToDateTime($sgs22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$apr12 = $app12.ConvertToDateTime($app12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$app22 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$apr22 = $app22.ConvertToDateTime($app22.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$spp12 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"


$spr12 = $spp12.ConvertToDateTime($spp12.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
$emailSmtpServer = "exmbx6"
$emailFrom = "gordonc@slhs.org"
$emailTo = "retinaAlert@slhs.org"
$emailSubject = "Result: Reboot report for $server $date" 
$emailSubjectF = "Stuff Failed"
$emailBody = @"
<p><strong>Todays Date</strong>:$date</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Server: SGSQL1</p>
<p> <strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr11</p>
<p> <strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SGSQL2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$sgr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$sgr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv1</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$apr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr12</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: Appv2</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$apr21</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$apr22</p>
<p>________________________________</p>
<p>Server: SltAppv4</p>
<p><strong>Pre Boot Time:</strong>$spr11</p>
<p><strong>Post Boot Time:</strong>$spr12</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Please close the Event Notifcation in FootPrints</p>
"@
#PostUptime
WorkedEmail
```

Without moving the body

Todays Date:07/09/2014 19:55:41
Server: SGSQL1
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:

---

Server: SGSQL2
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:

---

Server: Appv1
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:

---

Server: Appv2
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:

---

Server: SltAppv4
Pre Boot Time:
Post Boot Time:

With moving the body

Todays Date:07/09/2014 19:58:41
Server: SGSQL1
Pre Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:34:42 AM 
Post Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:34:42 AM

---

Server: SGSQL2
Pre Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:27:41 AM 
Post Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:27:41 AM

---

Server: Appv1
Pre Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:49:38 AM 
Post Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:49:38 AM

---

Server: Appv2
Pre Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:56:08 AM 
Post Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 12:56:08 AM

---

Server: SltAppv4
Pre Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 1:03:05 AM 
Post Boot Time: Wednesday, July 09, 2014 1:03:05 AM 
Please close the Event Notifcation in FootPrints

Comment: Are you saving that email body you generate somewhere apart from a global variable? Doesn't seem so. It will be lost when you reboot.

Comment: Um im running the whole script as a scheduled task on a server that should never be rebooted, so it recreated the email body every time the script runs. I made the script work moving the Post and Pre boot time out of the function it was housed in... I'm just not sure why I will not let my run the function and then pull information from the functions internal var's...

Comment: Correction... I had to drop my email body and such right under the post reboot time portion to get it to fill in correctly... Info in the main post..

Comment: Your code shows that you are calling ServerReboot function after preuptime and that will reboot the server.

Comment: Correct, I want to know when the last time the server was rebooted before I reboot the servers. This way when the post times are pulled that difference is reflected and shown works as a checks and balance.

Comment: Never mind. You are rebooting remote servers and not the local system. Right?

Comment: Correct the task is being ran on a server that I control. I should be using the $server to list the servers out.

Comment: I get it now. There are many things wrong about this script. I will respond with my solution.

Comment: Ugh I thought I had this working, however I could not get Function ServerReboot to run.. I was forced to take the code out of the function and throw it near the bottom to run. I'm not sure if im not calling the function correctly or what, any educational input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Cody

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I found my solution for setting Var inside of a function I have to use this $global tag ie $global:sgr11. Then I can call the $sgr11 without an problem. So that answers my question for that, however I'm still having issue calling the serverreboot function, however that might be a new question all together.

```
Function Preuptime{
$global:sgs11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql1"
$global:sgr11 = $sgs11.ConvertToDateTime($sgs11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:sgs21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sgsql2"
$global:sgr21 = $sgs21.ConvertToDateTime($sgs21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv1"
$global:apr11 = $app11.ConvertToDateTime($app11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:app21 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "appv2"
$global:apr21 = $app21.ConvertToDateTime($app21.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
#
$global:spp11 = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer "sltappv4"
$global:spr11 = $spp11.ConvertToDateTime($spp11.LastBootUpTime) | Out-String
}
```

PS C:\Users\gordonc> preuptime

PS C:\Users\gordonc> Write-Host @spr11

T h u r s d a y ,   J u l y   1 0 ,   2 0 1 4   1 : 3 5 : 0 4   A M

Answer (score 0):

As for my ServerReboot function I figured it out!!!

```
foreach($servers in $server){
            ping -n 2 $servers >$null
            if($lastexitcode -eq 0){
                Restart-Computer -Wait -For Wmi $servers
            } else {
                FailedEmail
                }
            }
}
```

Before I had $server in $servers where it should have been $servers in $server... Just a really basic mistake that took 8 youtube videos and lot of troubleshooting...